# How to draw half of pie in QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to draw half of pie like this in qGraphicsview framework.[image]

And I tried to draw  two pie and the color of one of them is transparent but it didn't work and i decided to ask  here.

Because I dont know QPainterPath very well, I was  unsuccessful to draw  arc and pie!.

Any answer oridea will be appreciated.

Comment: looks like a shaved cone to me :). Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: Have you managed to get anything drawing at all yet?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Neox, the picture is not really a pie ;). If you want an actual pie (that is: a segment of a circle) you can use the inbuilt method of painter:

```
QRect rect( -radius, -radius, radius*2, radius*2);
painter->drawPie( rect, startAngle*16, span*16 );
```

`int radius`
the radius of your pie, obviously.

`int startAngle`
 where your pie starts, e.g. 20° offset from the positive X axis

`int span`
number of degrees that the arc stretches, e.g. a pie with span = 320° would end at a total of 340°, or -20° from the positive X axis. (see QPainter Documentation for the miraculous *16)

This should give you a nice PacMan ^^ - or you can play around with the values.

Now, without any more details you need to figure out where to actually place this snippet. Naturally, it would be in the paint method of a some graphical item, e.g. a custom QGraphicsItem, and hence use the painter that comes as input to this method. This really depends on your setup of widgets and stuff...

Qt has actually a pretty awesome documentation, so make sure to check this out first: (I've only been at it for two weeks myself, but you can get pretty far with the documentation)

QGraphicsItem: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html
QPainter: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html

Cheers,
Louise

PS: First answer, yay!

Comment: And once you have managed to draw the pie slice properly, you could then subsequently paint a smaller radius version with Qt.transparent color to shave off the area towards the circle origin

Answer (score 1):

Erasing is not practical because very soon you will be erasing other stuff in image or at least you need to be very careful in which order you draw things.

Literally, if you are looking for a way to draw a pie, the drawPie() method does it but looking at the example image you gave you looking for a pie like segment of a washer.

Something like this:

[image]

This was produced with code like this:

```
QImage image(width,height,QImage::Format_ARGB32); 
image.fill(qRgba(0,0,0,0)); // clear and make transparent

QPainter painter; // use a painter to draw to the image
painter.begin(&image);

// center at (0,0) and scale so that range [-1,1] cover whole image
QTransform transform;
transform.translate(texSize/2, texSize/2);
transform.scale(texSize/2, -texSize/2);
painter.setTransform(transform);

// outer and inner washer dimensions
QRectF r1(-1, -1, 2, 2);
QRectF r2(-0.5, -0.5, 1, 1);

//-------------- this is the essence of the matter -------------
// create a path with two arcs to form the outline
QPainterPath path;
path.arcTo(r1,0,90);  // from 3 'clock 90 degrees cw
path.arcTo(r2,90,-90); // from 12 'clock 90 degrees ccw
//--------------------------------------------------------------

// and finally fill it
painter.fillPath(path, Qt::green);

// save it to file
image.save(QLatin1String("testimage.png"));
```

Granted above does not do it with QGraphicsItem. However I believe you should be doing this QGraphicsPathItem and lift the code from above to create the path.

I did not want to post code that uses QGraphicsPathItem because I do not have time to test that code but I believe above code snippet solves the essential difficulty of how to create the geometry in the first place.